# How to use Popen to open a file with space in its name with default program in windows?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

The following code can open the test.txt file with notepad

`subprocess.Popen(['start','test.txt'],shell=True)`

But this won't open a file with a space in its name like 'the test.txt'.

I've tried using raw string(r'...'), double quote on cmd, '%20' to substitute the space, but none of that works.

Comment: I don't have Windows open at the moment, but since no one's jumped in yet, here are some guesses. Loose the list and do `'start "the text.txt"'`. Or maybe even just `'"the test.txt"'`. That is, make sure the double quotes are passed to the shell.

Comment: The term "namespace" means something else entirely than "a name with a space in it".

Comment: For what it's worth, raw strings in Python only change the meaning of the backslash character, which gets interpreted by Python in regular, non-raw strings. There are no backslashes here, so using a raw string changes nothing.

Comment: on Linux you can use `\ ` in shell to put space in filename - like `'start the\ test.txt'` - maybe it will work in Windows. But on Linux you can also use `" "` (insides `' '`) or `' '` (inside `" "`) - like `'start "the test.txt"'` or `"start 'the test.txt'"`. And value `%20` is used only in urls.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a list of arguments with `shell=True` happens to generally work on Windows, but is really never correct. Of course, `start` is a shell (`cmd`) command, so you need a shell here; but then, you also need to quote the string for the shell.

```
subproces.run('start "the test.txt"', shell=True)
```

Notice also that I switched to `subprocess.run()`; you generally want to avoid raw `Popen` whenever you can, as also suggested in the documentation.

Comment: Windows commands always run with `shell=True` regradless of what you tell popen if I understand correctly.

Answer (score -3):

It's much easier to rename the file with an underscore or dash etc.

I had a similar issue once with a client. I'm fairly certain we concluded by renaming by hand all of the necessary files to replace a space with an underscore.
Unless python have released a patch (or indeed, I was oblivious), I think it may be impossible.
Python reads a space and goes "okay, thats that command, what's next?" and then reads whatever follows the space, excluding certain things like string variables.

Take these lines

```
import os
os.system("start EXCEL.EXE my workbook.xlsb")
```

Python of course imports the os module here, then in line two it runs the os.system command with the parameters; start, EXCEL.EXE, my, workbook.xlsb
in fact it doesn't, once it reaches the filename "my" without an extension it quits and throws an error in the shell.

Comment: Good luck renaming anything on read-only medium.

Comment: Nobody mentioned read only drives though? The asker didn't say his drive is read only so I didn't take it into account